# How can i invoke a during compiletime unknown native function from C#

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, native

During runtime i am supplied with a `String` name, a sorted array of objects and some additional information about a native function (dllpath, calltype, etc).

lets assume all information was in a `CallInformation` Object.

How can i call this native function?

note:
- i am not supplied with the dll before runtime.
- i am not supplied with the call information before runtime.
- i dont know the ammount or types of call parameter before runtime.
- i dont know the returntype before runtime.

The [usual information on the web](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27298/Dynamic-Invoke-C-DLL-function-in-C) about calling native functions deals with invoking

- known functionstypes in known dlls
- known functionstypes in unknown dlls

What i need is

- unknown functionstypes in unknown dlls

Comment: I rolled the edit back because it is important that the function is not simply unknown, but unknown during compiletime. it could be an unknown function where i am supplied information during compiletime to help me import an unknown function... like with a regular pinvoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would involve Reflection.Emit. You have to dynamically generate a class containing your PInvoke signature decorated with the appropriate DllImport attribute based on your CallInformation.
Sorry that there is no code, but it can't be boiled down to something worthy to post, considering the verbose Reflection.Emit API.

Comment: code.google.com/p/dynamicdllimport/ This project contains code that are you loking for

Comment: This is probably the only way of creating a delegate dynamically that can be used for interop, since generic delegates like System.Func<...> [cannot be used in interop scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer.aspx#Y100).

Answer (score 1):

Make a delegate signature dynamically and call it using reflection.
Just look up how to create delegates dynamically, how to load a native function, how to call a function using reflection and connect those together.