# How can I call C++ function from C# project

Tags: c#, c++, function

I have a C# project and I want to protect it by using Desctop Window Manager function: SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hwnd, WDA_MONITOR); it`s on C++. How can I call this function from my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do it like this, using [pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowDisplayAffinity.html).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowDisplayAffinity(IntPtr hwnd, DisplayAffinity affinity);

enum DisplayAffinity : uint
{
   None = 0,
   Monitor = 1
}
```

after defining this. Call this method.

Answer (score 0):

[msdn has a whole chapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235281.aspx) on the topic.

If you know the dll that the function is in [things get easier with pinvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx).

If you know even less at compile time there are [other questions on stckoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850893/how-can-i-invoke-a-during-compiletime-unknown-native-function-from-c-sharp) that help you.